# How to receive notices with PyGreSQL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, pgdb

I'm using PyGreSQL 4.1.1 with Postgres 9.5, and have written some stored functions. I use `RAISE` with different levels inside of the functions for debugging purposes, which works very well in `psql`, but I haven't found a way to access those messages in Python.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $_$
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A notice from my function.';
        RETURN TRUE;
    END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My Python code looks like this:

```
conn = pgdb.connect(database = 'mydb', user = 'myself')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT my_function()"):
```

How can I access the notice (`A notice from my function.`) after running `my_function()`?

Comment: [Connection.set_notice_receiver(func)](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/connection.html#pg.Connection.set_notice_receiver)

Comment: @klin: Thanks, but `set_notice_receiver()` is apparently out of the `pg` module. Is there also a variant for `pgdb`?

Comment: Unfortunately, notices are not included in DB-API 2.0 as it's a feature specific for Postgres.

Comment: @klin: Thank you for you hint. I found a solution based on this, which I have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to @klin's comment I found a somewhat unclean solution. The `pgdb.Connection` object stores the underlying `pg.Connection` object in a *private* property named `_cnx`. Thus, you can set the notice receiver like this:

```
def my_notice_receiver(notice):
    logging.info("Notice: %s", notice)

conn._cnx.set_notice_receiver(my_notice_receiver)
```